# Posting multiple "answers" to an already answered question

Tags: discussion, answers, bumping

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/436983/finding-closed-subspaces-whose-sum-isnt-closed) was asked and correctly answered three weeks ago. Since then another user has posted, as of today, five other "answers" describing his thoughts about related questions, attempts that failed, etc.

A week ago I suggested in a comment to him that these multiple answers are probably not appropriate for MathOverflow, but was rebuffed with "I understand your point but I think that the discussion has a natural evolution. Anyone not interested on this he can simply skip it. It is so simple."

I've previously complained about really excessive edits to a question which repeatedly push it to the top of the page, thereby pushing other questions down. ("Really excessive" is the key phrase here.) Should really excessive answers be viewed in a similar way?

Comment: I can understand why these answers would be frustrating for you, and I might well feel the same way if I were in your shoes—but, in the spirit that contributions to MO are for everyone's good, not just the asker's, isn't this a perfect place for votes of the community at large to sort out, as it were, the wheat from the chaff?  Each of the answers currently has at least one upvote, and no downvote, so at least one person has found each useful, and no-one has found any answer not useful to the extent of expressing that opinion with a vote.

Comment: @LSpice I imagine that the upvote comes from the only person who seems able to engage with what is (a world expert) thinking aloud. I am not a specialist in Banach space theory but it does seem that Prof. Argyros is using the MO answer boxes like posting to a forum...

Comment: Argyros' account appears now to be suspended (for 7 days).

Comment: IMHO, in principle, it is even desirable if a post has “a natural evolution”, and new aspects emerge; however, for the readers’ sake, it would be better to avoid a stream of consciousness on the same place. Rather, it seems more practical to post a new question as follow-up, focusing on a precise new aspect of the question.